# Rails installation advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Just can't seem to get Rails installed on my macbook Air.

Started following the tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
Installed RVM, Homebrew, Ruby 2.0.0, GCC compiler and XCode command line tools 
These are all installed fine.

Just can't get passed the final step of installing Rails. Over the last 2 days, I've read every blog post and installation guide. Still no luck. This is my last option, so I hope someone can see what I've left out.

This is the error message I get when I run gem install rails:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

and this is the content of the mkmf.log mentioned in the error message:

```
" -o conftest -I/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0 -I/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/active/include -fPIC -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib -L.  -L/Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/active/lib -L/usr/lib -fPIC -Bstatic -fstack-protector   -arch x86_64   -lruby-static  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: First make sure you have a current RVM version i.e. `rvm get stable`, maybe try to re-install Ruby 2.0.0. If that doesn't solve the problem it may be a GCC issue. How did you install GCC? What is the output of `gcc -v`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like an issue with installing Ruby. Install it separately, or try installing 1.9.3.

Comment: did you follow the installation chapter of this book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning?version=4.0#sec-rubygems ? he makes you install several libraries before installing ruby (libtool, libxslt, libksba, openssl, and libyaml). I strictly followed the installation chapter and it worked fine.

Comment: I have the latest stable version of RVM. gcc -v output is too long to post here. 
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: I followed the installation in the link you gave. The dependencies were slightly longer than those in the article. I let RVM download everything that was required for the Ruby install. I installed GCC as explained here http://www.rackspace.com/blog/installing-rails-on-a-mac/

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is an issue with installing Ruby? It may help me if you could show me which part of the error message indicates this. Ruby seems to be installed fine. It is the Rails gem I can't install.

Comment: I had the same problem. Tried all sorts of methods I found, but the last thing that got it working was reinstalling ruby. Try `sudo rvm get stable` then `sudo rvm reinstall ruby`.

Comment: Thanks. I went through and updated everything and finally got it working!

Comment: @resting thanks so much! After so many unsuccessful attempts it is finally working.